# Putting Illustrator CS4 in fullscreen?

Tags: fullscreen, adobe-illustrator, adobe-cs4

so I got this drawing tool (thats basically a really big mouse and a magnetic pen) from my good friend because he got a bigger and better one and I have the Adobe Suite CS4. But, I'm not a good drawer so I am interested in learning and I kind of want to turn Illustrator into a canvas that takes up the whole screen. In addition, I don't want the window to be shown at all. Is there any way to do this? Photoshop or another alternative works also works but I would prefer Illustrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key <kbd>f</kbd> cycles through full-screen modes in Illustrator.

Comment: O yeah it does! Thnx!

Comment: Also press TAB to show/hide the toolbars, in any mode.